# SQL Server 2008: I/O Wait Time per Database File

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition and want to monitor the following performance metrics i.e. via dynamic management views (from within SQL):

> Average/Maximum Read/Write **I/O Waits** in ms **per database file**
>   for sliding time window.

That is: 4 numbers per database file: avg read wait, max read wait, avg write wait, max write wait. All in ms, and all for some sane (or even better configurable) sliding time window.

How can I do that?

PS: I have the VIEW SERVER STATE permission and can read `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`, `sys.database_files`, `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` etc etc

PS2: At least 1 tool (Quest Spotlight 7 for SQL Server) is able to provide Max I/O Wait in ms per database file. So there has to be some way ..

Comment: Couldn't you just use your servers performance monitor in your server manager over the time frame you need and log the results instead then you will have both a visual aid and raw numbers available to you in a format that is easy to read and explain to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the query that SSMS's Activie Monitor uses.  They label the io_stall field as total wait time.  You could add the `fs.io_stall_read_ms` and `fs.io_stall_write_ms` fields to get the read/write specific numbers.

```
SELECT     
    d.name AS [Database], 
    f.physical_name AS [File], 
    (fs.num_of_bytes_read / 1024.0 / 1024.0) [Total MB Read], 
    (fs.num_of_bytes_written / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [Total MB Written], 
    (fs.num_of_reads + fs.num_of_writes) AS [Total I/O Count], 
    fs.io_stall AS [Total I/O Wait Time (ms)], 
    fs.size_on_disk_bytes / 1024 / 1024 AS [Size (MB)],
    fs.io_stall_read_ms
FROM sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(default, default) AS fs
INNER JOIN sys.master_files f ON fs.database_id = f.database_id AND fs.file_id = f.file_id
INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = fs.database_id;
```

This query only gives you the totals.  You'd have to run it at some interval and record the results in a temp table with a time stamp. You could then query this table to get your min/max/avg as needed.  The sliding time window would just be a function of how much data you keep in that table and what time period you query.

Comment: Ok, `io_stall_write_ms` gives "Total time, in milliseconds, that users waited for writes to be completed on the file.". How can this be used to compute the _Max._ Write Wait time for the respective file? I can compute the avg. (total/count), but the max?

Comment: I don't see a simple way to do it. Assuming you store the results in a table as mentioned, you'd have to compute the change in wait time per observation.  You would then take the max of the change.

Comment: Though the answer doesn't reveal how to get max I/O waits per file, I give the bounty to this answer since it provided an actual SQL query and the most details.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are going to have is that SQL doesn't necessarily track the level of detail you are looking to get per file. You are probably going to have to use Performance monitor as well. You will have to use a combination approach looking at both performance monitor for details on I/O on the disk over the course of time. As well as the aforementioned SQL monitoring techniques to see get a more complete complete picture. I hope that helps.

Comment: Spotlight for SQL Server is able to report the metric I am most interested in: _max._ Read/Write time per database file in ms (over a sliding window). So there seems to exist a way .. I just don't know how;) Which is why I offer a bounty ..

Answer (score 2):

You can use a few scripts to pull the metrics. I have enebled the Data Collection/Data Collection server built in to SQL Server 8. It collects the metrics from multiple instances and stores them in a mssql server you designate as the collector. The reports provided for each instance are adequate for most purposes. I am sure there are 3rd party tools that go beyond the capabilities of the data collector as it just reports on performance/disk usage/and query statistics without performance hints.

This gives you a data file growth projection and growth event summary for both logs and data files, however, I do not know if it will give you the metrics you are looking for per file or filegroup:)

NOTE: If you use the data collection warehouse you should consider rebuilding indexes periodically as the size grows. It collects approx. 20 MB/day of data in my senario.

Comment: Well, thats all fine, but I am interested in exactly the metrics stated in the question. Question wasn't about collecting metrics from different instances or collecting size metrics ..

Answer (score 2):

See the following for collecting per file wait statistics http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187309(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This function seems to return the same data as `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` which unfortunately does not include _max_ wait times on a file. How do I get max. I/O stall time in ms?

Comment: Metrics are collected over a period of time. Restated max stall time is the stall time for the period monitored, nothing more store the results in a table and apply a max function

Comment: The value is the stall time accumulated for all I/Os on a file over a period. Computing a max over different periods isn't what I want. I need the max over the set of individual I/O stall times within a period. For a fast disk, this value will be 5-10ms, and when >10ms, it's an indicator that storage latency is an issue.